# Why when I click on the checkbox doesn't call the function onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick

```js
function click()
{
  alert("function is called");
}
```

```html
<form action="regCheck.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return submitF()">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs" onclick="click()"/>
</form>
```

This is not my real file. I'm just writing this part of my code so you people could see why my ***onclick*** function is not being called. If the javascript opens a window of alert when I click the checkbox, then it means I can use it. I hope you can help me. 
***Thanks!***

Answer (score 2):

Just change the name of your function from `"click"` to another name, so that it's not shadowed by a [the native `click` function of the input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)):

```js
function notcalledclick()
{
  alert("function is called");
}
```

```html
<form action="regCheck.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return submitF()">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxs" onclick="notcalledclick()"/>
</form>
```

This is another reason to avoid adding inline javascript and prefer `addEventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert("function is called");
});
```

```html
<form action="regCheck.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return submitF()">
  <input id=someId type="checkbox" name="checkboxs"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function name should change.

There's already a function called click, responsible for calling the event handler. By declaring another, you override the first, so the event doesn't work anymore.